# Import file in MAMP(file size exceeded the maximum size permitted)

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I want to import a file(85 MB) at my local server.

I changed in the `php.ini` the following values of the three variables (upload_max_filesize, memory_limit and post_max_size) exactly as I saw at same problems, with the right order, I restarted my MAMP server and my laptop but it didn't change anything and I can't import files more than 2 MB.

Can you give any advise to fix it ?

Comment: check from the phpinfo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import table in phpmyadmin? I got error of file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644872/how-to-import-table-in-phpmyadmin-i-got-error-of-file-size)

Comment: create a phpinfo.php page with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it to see if you changed the correct php.ini.  If the values didn't update after you made your change, you're editing the wrong file.  You can see the path to the correct .ini file in the phpinfo() info

Comment: the correct syntax is `upload_max_filesize = 10M` - **NO `B` AT THE END**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did all these things but nothing happened.I have two files with the name "php.ini",the first is "php.ini-development" and the second is "php.ini-production".Because i don't know which is the correct file to change the values,i changed the values and at the two because my phpinfo have like a Loaded Configuration File this:"C:\MAMP\conf\php7.0.13\php.ini" and not one of the two.

Answer (score 10):

You need to edit the `php.ini` file for the php version you are using. i.e. v7.2.1.
First check which version you're using by going to

```
MAMP-> Preferences -> PHP -> Select/Specify PHP Version
```

Then go to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini` and input the new settings there.

Stop your server and restart MAMP. Import should now run as expected.

Cheers.

Comment: However, change the ```post_max_size = 8M```

Answer (score 9):

Once you find out which version of PHP your MAMP is running, find the `php.ini` file at `C:\MAMP\conf\php7.2.10\php.ini`.

You'll need to change BOTH `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. If you only update the first, it'll default to the `post_max_size`.

Restart the MAMP and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

First check your PHP version

[image]

then according to your php version you have to go this php version file (php.ini)
and the change like below... :)

```
post_max_size = 256M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 256M

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_execution_time = 600     

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
max_input_time = 600

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
memory_limit = 512M
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing timeouts, you can increase `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time`.